# TextView drawableTop trick does not work in java?

Tags: android, android-layout

In **XML** you can set a `TextView` to have a `android:drawableTop`  however, in the java code, there is no corresponding `textView.setDrawableTop()`  why am I not seeing this? Shouldn't it be there?

Comment: I suspect its because drawableTop  is part of com.android.internal... http://codesearch.google.com/#tDMD2dgtPRg/trunk/framework/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java&q=android%20drawableTop&type=cs&l=506

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`textview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);` method works for the following

```
android:drawableBottom
        android:drawableLeft
        android:drawableRight
```